# REST - supporting multiple possible identifiers

Tags: api, url, rest, url-rewriting

For the site I am working on, we are in the process of improving our URLs for one type of resource - specifically, moving away from numerical IDs toward unique, descriptive strings. A similar example would be switching from identifying users by numerical database ID to identifying them by username (not our specific case, but analagous). So a URL to access a user's information used to look like:

```
/users/48573
```

And now it looks like

```
/users/thisisausername.
```

The only problem is that we still need to be able to fetch them through numerical IDs somehow, for legacy consumers of the API. We don't need the REST URLs themselves to redirect (e.g. `/users/48573` should not redirect to `/users/thisisausername`), we just need a method to obtain the right data using the old identifier. The solution should either provide an alternate way of accessing the user information (which conveniently includes the new identifier, username) by ID, or of accessing just the username by ID. Some possible solutions might be:

- Using a node to specify some alternate method of identification, e.g. `/users/byid/48573`
- Using a query parameter to specify some alternate method of identification, e.g. `/users/48573?fetchby=id` or `/users/48573?byid=true`
- Treating username-by-id as another resource, e.g. `/identifiers/username/48573`

Which of these (if any) is closest to proper REST? How would you deal with the problem?

Comment: I ended up implementing access via non-principal-identifier fields as a search. 

This solution allows for fetching multiple types of resources via multiple fields, while maintaining just one as the primary identifier. For consistency, the "search" APIs return lists. 

So the official way to access a user is:

/user/thisisausername

and to access by ID, we have:

/users?id=48573

Similarly, we could search on a number of different fields, as in:

/users?firstName=Kelly

Inspiration was from: http://jwyseur.blogspot.com/2008/12/uri-design-for-rest.html (see "searching a resource")

Comment: So you punted on caching?  I have the same issue as you, but cannot solve them problem via query parameters that remove one of the primary benefits of a REST API.  I like your first bulleted suggestion...

Answer (score 42):

I think adding a path segment/prefix is the best answer. Since these are unique secondary keys, this isn't the same as search (which returns a set of items), so using query parameters (which aren't cached) doesn't seem like the best choice.

Personally, I plan to use a path segment prefix delimited by "=", like "name=" or "email=":

```
user/123456
user/name=john.doe
user/email=john.doe@john.doe
```

This is functionally equivalent to adding a path segment (e.g. "user/name/john.doe"), but feels to me like it maps more closely to the conceptual model. Of course, this is an insignificant detail, since RESTful APIs shouldn't specify a fixed URI structure anyway.

Not using query parameters also allows sub-resources to be accessed naturally:

```
user/name=john.doe/inbox/df87bhJXrg63
```

Frameworks like Java's JAX-RS support using whatever delimiter you want:

```
@GET
@Path("user/{id}")
User getUser(@PathParam("id") UUID id);

@GET
@Path("user/name={name}")
User getUserByName(@PathParam("name") String name);

@GET
@Path("user/email={email}")
User getUserByEmail(@PathParam("email") String email);
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach I've not seen before. It solves the problem nicely, but I just can't get past the fact that seeing the equals sign outside of query parameters seems like it'll cause confusion...

Comment: Plus, it's not very restful.  what, exactly, is the collection name=john.doe?  To me it should be a matrix parameter:
user;name=john.doe/inbox/df87...

http://blog.2partsmagic.com/restful-uri-design/

Comment: @Maladon I think you're missing the point. `name=john.doe` shouldn't be a collection, since `name` is a unique identifier. We're looking for exactly one object or an error. `user;name=john.doe` looks like a search. I'd expect it to return the same representation as `user`, which is a collection.

Comment: More appropriate would be `/user?email=john.doe@john.doe` (or, when properly encoded: `/user?email=john.doe%40john.doe`)

Comment: More-more appropriate would be `/users?email=john.doe@john.doe` where you're actually querying the 'users' collection using the filter called 'email'. But this also implies that the result will be an array with 'most likely' a single element.

Answer (score 24):

Your first option is probably the best.

Searching for users by ID:

```
/users/id/48573
```

Searching for users by short name:

```
/users/name/thisisausername
```

If they leave out that path parameter, you could always default to your new short username format.

Another option that I have seen quite a bit is to use query parameters like the following:

```
/users?id=48573
/users?name=thisisausername
```

I think the first looks a bit cleaner and more readable.

Answer (score -3):

Quite an old question but I had the same and finnaly found the solution :
use regex in your path param.

Here's how I coded that use case

```
@GET
@Path("/{id : \\d+}")
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
 <<your code>>
}

@GET
@Path("/{name}")
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getByName(@PathParam("name") String name) {
 <<your code>>
}
```

Comment: What if the name of the user is numeric? If a user can chose his name freely and decides to only use a number your approach fails.

Comment: it fails or not. You have to make controls on creation (POST) request and can refuse numeric only name.

Comment: @@POST
    public Response create(@Valid User user) 

and annotate your model with bean validation. Exemple : must begin with a Capitalized letter, 50 char max

    @@Pattern(regexp = "[A-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9- ]{0,49}", message = "invalid name")
    private String name;

Comment: What if we're not working with users and usernames but are instead working with products, that have both an (internal) id and an (external) numeric code, like a EAN? This solution may fit the question, but it's not generic enough, IMHO.

Comment: @watery your internal and external ids could have different length, then it is still possible to use this solution. At last query parameters are still usable if you can't distinct which id it is.

    products?id=12345678 or
    products?ean=65833254

Answer (score -4):

I'd consider qualifying the string with an optional suffix:

```
/users/48573/id

/users/48573/name
```

If you receive a string without the suffix:

```
/users/48573
```

then you check the string and see if it's an ID or Name.

If you only get a valid ID but not a name then it's a retrieval by ID equivalent to:

```
/users/48573/id
```

If you only get a name back then it's a retrieval by Name equivalent to:

```
/users/48573/name
```

If you can retrieve the value by ID or Name then you return a 300 response error and return links to both possiblities to the client:

```
/users/48573/id

/users/48573/name
```

The legacy consumers continue to work 'as is' except for the occasional occurence of duplicate ID/name pairs where they receive the new 300 response error.

Comment: This is not REST at all. This is just RPC.

Answer (score -5):

Your API is not RESTful if this is an issue. To [quote](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) Roy Fielding:

> A REST API must not define fixed resource names or hierarchies (an obvious coupling of client and server). Servers must have the freedom to control their own namespace. Instead, allow servers to instruct clients on how to construct appropriate URIs, such as is done in HTML forms and URI templates, by defining those instructions within media types and link relations. [Failure here implies that clients are assuming a resource structure due to out-of band information, such as a domain-specific standard, which is the data-oriented equivalent to RPC's functional coupling].
>
> A REST API should be entered with no prior knowledge beyond the initial URI (bookmark) and set of standardized media types that are appropriate for the intended audience (i.e., expected to be understood by any client that might use the API). From that point on, all application state transitions must be driven by client selection of server-provided choices that are present in the received representations or implied by the user’s manipulation of those representations. The transitions may be determined (or limited by) the client’s knowledge of media types and resource communication mechanisms, both of which may be improved on-the-fly (e.g., code-on-demand). [Failure here implies that out-of-band information is driving interaction instead of hypertext.]

Comment: This is not an answer to his question.  A REST API can support HATEOAS all day long, and yet the server developers still need to worry about the issues of URI design.