# Web-Service request with parameter in C#

Tags: c#, rest, parameter-passing, httpwebresponse, .net-4.5.2

I have web rest services which take one parameter that is studentID and bring back with the student record. I am having difficulty in order to pass parameter to service and its literately not happening

```
string StudentByPeopleCodeServiceURL = https://agentwebservices.ac.uk/Rest/Modules/15427/Screens/U_LookUps/Data/StudentByCode
```

parameter that I need to pass is

```
{PeopeCode}= 307242
```

and code is

```
HttpWebRequest _Request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(StudentByPeopleCodeServiceURL));

   try
       {
         _Request.Method = "GET";

         _Request.ContentType = "text/xml";

         _Request.Accept = "text/xml";

         _Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+5.01;+Windows+NT+5.0";

   _Request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-us");

   _Request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, token.EBS_Token);

 HttpWebResponse _Response = _Request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;


   _WebServiceStatus.ResponseStatusCode = _Response.StatusCode;
   _WebServiceStatus.ResponseContentLength = _Response.ContentLength;
   _WebServiceStatus.ResponseContentType = _Response.ContentType;

    //rest of code
```

i have tried passing parameter in url like ?PeopeCode= 307242 but it is not working. The Rest API is external and I don't have any control on it

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You mean `?PeopleCode=307242` right? You've missed out the L both times.

Comment: yes...I know i miss spell but still same issue not working

Comment: If the spelling is correct in your real code then please correct it here. You says "it's not working". How? Error message? Empty value returned? If it's not passed as part of the URL it's possible it has to be submitted some other way such as POST, only the API documentation can tell you this.

Comment: Do you have access to the endpoint documentation ? Can you show a working example to compare ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a rest web service, try to add the parameter "{PeopeCode}= 307242" to the url like the following example:

```
https://agentwebservices.ac.uk/Rest/Modules/15427/Screens/U_LookUps/Data/StudentByCode/307242
```

Normally the querystring is related to search scenarios : [REST API DESIGN - Getting a resource through REST with different parameters but same url pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381976/rest-api-design-getting-a-resource-through-rest-with-different-parameters-but)