# ASP.NET Core - Different endpoint is being called

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have following a ASP.NET Core Web Api endpoints:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetApplications([FromQuery] PaginationParameters paginationParameters)
{
}

[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetApplicationById(int id, string full)
{
}

[HttpGet("{uuid}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetApplicationByUUID(string uuid, string full)
{
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> InsertApplications([FromBody] Application toInsertApplication)
{
}
```

The controller is called `ApplicationController` and is marked with following Attributes:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
```

Now when I call the endpoint with the `uuid` parameter like so: `https://localhost:3333/api/Application?uuid=123asd-123asdasd-wqeasdad` then the first endpoint `GetApplications` gets triggered instead of the `uuid` one.

When using following url: `https://localhost:3333/api/Application/123asd-123asdasd-wqeasdad` everything works fine and the correct endpoint is triggered.

Why is this happening? This is code from one of our company apis but I reproduced this in a minimalistic example at home where I get the same behaviour.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The second URL which is with the `uuid` as path of URL, which the 3rd API action is matched. While the first URL which is with the `uuid` as query parameter, it won't hit the 3rd API action, but will go to the first API action.

Comment: One possible way is you could use action selector attribute to select which action the request go to based on the query string. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionconstraints.actionmethodselectorattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: @YongShun yea I know that it does that but why? It should not find any matching routes

Comment: This is the asp.net core route mapping rule. The route mapping will not auto mapping the ?uuid=xxx to the [HttpGet("{uuid}")], since the [HttpGet("{uuid}")] is the url pattern not the query string format.

Comment: @BrandoZhang Yes I know the difference between path and query parameters. But when calling the url with the query parameter it should not find any matching endpoints to call. That my problem here. As far as I can see ther eis no endpoint that specifies a query paramter with the name uuid for example with [FromQuery]. Now why it just triggers the GetApplications is a mystery to me

Comment: https://localhost:3333/api/Application?uuid=123asd-123asdasd-wqeasda, ?querysting is not the part of the route, so it will trigger the [HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetApplications

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the `uuid` as part of the url path, so the correct url to call is:
`https://localhost:3333/api/Application/123asd-123asdasd-wqeasdad`

See that you have on controller the attribute defining `api/[controller]` and that becomes part of the url, it is the same with you defining `uuid` as being part of the url path.

If you want to be a query value, then you can only have a single endpoint, so you will need to delete that action with `uuid`, and add it to top method.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetApplications([FromQuery] PaginationParameters paginationParameters, [FromQuery] string uuid)
{
}
```

However, I would recommend you use named endpoints to get what you want.

```
[HttpGet("ByID/{id:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetApplicationById(int id, string full)
{
}

[HttpGet("ByUUID/{uuid}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetApplicationByUUID(string uuid, string full)
{
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Would your suggested way of naming the endpoints be conform with rest conventions? When thinking straight the GetApplications function should have nothing to do with the uuid parameter and it does not even belong here. It should throw an error that no matching routes were found and not just trigger the first endpoint.

Comment: Yeah, GetApplications shouldn't have uuid, I just wanted to point out the error in defining the route. As for REST conformation, REST is not really a strict standard to follow, it is more like a convention, I would personally use this, but something similar can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20386425/1151151

Comment: What I also found out: The GetApplications endpoint has not Route specified. If I specify something for example [HttpGet("Whatever")] then I get a MethodNotAllowed when calling with query parameter instead of path parameter so that should be the solution but it makes the namimg of the different endpoints a bit confusing

Comment: @Florent `[HttpGet("Whatever")]` defines a specific route (and any other attribute routing like HttpPost, HttpPut,etc), so it will map to `/api/Application/Whatever`, so you get MethodNotAllowed because the path maps to `InsertApplications` which is HttpPost.

Comment: So you want to tell me that I do a get request and it tries to execute the post request? The post request should not be considered to begin with when I am doing a get request. Weird behavior